# Python lxml: Strange issue with reading repeated elements and storing in a list

Tags: python, xml, parsing, list, lxml

I'm running into a bizarre issue. I've had two very different versions of code to solve the same issue, and have run into the same problem.

I have simplified the problem down to this:

Here is the xml file:

```
<Test>
 <Object name="Ob1">
  <List/>
 </Object>

 <Object name="Ob2">
  <List>
   <item>One</item>
   <item>Two</item>
  </List>
 </Object>

 <Object name="Ob3">
  <List>
   <item>Three</item>
   <item>Four</item>
   <item>Five</item>
  </List>
 </Object>
</Test>
```

Here is the python code:

```
from lxml import etree

#Load XML

fileobject = open("list_test.xml", "r") #read-only
parser = etree.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True)
tree = etree.parse(fileobject, parser)
root = tree.getroot()

object_list = []

class TestClass():
    name = None
    list = []


for OB in root:
    temp_ob = TestClass()
    temp_ob.name = OB.get("name")
    for SubElem in OB:
        if SubElem.tag == "List":
            for item in SubElem:
                if item.tag == "item":
                    temp_ob.list.append(item.text)
    object_list.append(temp_ob)
    del temp_ob

for ob in object_list:
    print ob.name
    print ob.list
```

The code is supposed to store all the `<item>` elements in a list in an object, which is itself stored in a list.

However, here is the output I am getting:

```
Ob1
['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five']
Ob2
['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five']
Ob3
['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five']
```

Why is it getting all the `<item>` elements in the WHOLE document?

Comment: Just for the record, this is an issue in a far more complex program, but I seem to have narrowed the problem down to the .append statement. Just a thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `TestClass.list` is a **class-level attribute**, so each `object_list.append()` is happening on the same list.

For example:

```
class Foo(object):
    lst = []

f1 = Foo()
f1.lst.append(1)
f2 = Foo()
f2.lst.append(2)
print f1.lst
print f2.lst

[1, 2]
[1, 2]
```

You should make it an **instance-level attribute**:

```
class Bar(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.lst = []

b1 = Bar()
b1.lst.append(1)
b2 = Bar()
b2.lst.append(2)
print b1.lst
print b2.lst

[1]
[2]
```

Comment: So basically, the list[] is the same one for each object? Not a new one for each object?

Comment: Yeah, it is a single `[]` allocated at the class level. The 2nd syntax above (Bar) will give you a new list for each instance of TestClass.